# Import Error Openpose in Python project with Mac OS

Tags: python, macos, openpose

I have installed OpenPose in MacOSX, and I can execute the examples like this:

```
'./build/examples/openpose/openpose.bin --video examples/media/video.avi'
```

But **I cannot import/use the Openpose library in Python projects.**

In Openpose folder I've done:

```
cd build/python
sudo make install
```

And export variable:
vim ~/.bashrc

```
#(Add this line to the end of the file)
export PYTHONPATH=/path/to/openpose/build/python:
```

But when I try to import from Python console:

```
➜ python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct  6 2017, 22:29:07)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.31)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import openpose
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named openpose
```

Any ideas on how to solve this to be able to use Openpose from a Python project?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try to `source ~/.bashrc`?

Comment: Yes, and I get:
    /Users/sm/.bashrc:export:13: not valid in this context: 
    /Users/sm/POCs/openpose/build/python

Comment: Please add the output of `sudo make install`.